# What skills in today's market as a webmaster have the most value?

Tags: marketing, value, skills

From your experience, based on supply, demand, and effort to learn -- What skills in today's market as a webmaster have the most value? Second, if you were evaluating another webmaster on that skill, what factors would be the best indicators of their level of expertise?

Comment: This is subjective and probably should be community wiki

Comment: Second question that you commented on saying it's not a good question, find it interesting that you've answered so many questions... yet never asked ONE question. Why?

Comment: I didn't say either question wasn't a good one. One is in the incorrect place and the other is subjective and needs to be marked as such. The questions themselves are very good ones. They just need to be properly placed. That's all. And I haven't asked any questions yet because I don't have anything I need an answer for yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on it:  best skill would be "ability to learn fast and evolve", to keep on top of current technologies, and to decide/advice on what is the next big thing and invest in it. (subjective example: should you invest in Silverlight or HTML5 ?).

Next on the list, don't be specialized in a particular platform: Linux/Windows/OSX/mobile are all there.

And if you want to target niches, accessibility expertise is nice to have.

Comment: I have to say that you should be specialized in a platform.  For example, if I was looking to hire someone for Linux server work admin work, I would never hire someone who says they work on windows servers and Linux.  I want someone who ONLY works on Linux servers.  Never trust someone or a company who spreads themselves too thin.